# MySQL- Case Condition Error

Tags: mysql, case

I am having an issue with the following Case statement in MySQL:

```
CASE  
    WHEN 
    ((SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -2) = ('Provider - Remote Client - North')) then SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -1)
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -2)
END CASE
```

I get the error 'unexpected then'
Can anyone advise?!? 
Thanks

Comment: First thing I see is a missing bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an parentheses in the `WHEN` and you have an extra `CASE` after the `END`:

```
CASE  
    WHEN 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -2) = 'Provider - Remote Client - North'
    THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -1)
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -2)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and use parenthesis only where needed. There is one too much.

This is the correct query:

```
CASE  
    WHEN 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -2) = 'Provider - Remote Client - North') 
        THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -1)
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX('Provider - Remote Client - North', '-', -2)
END CASE
```